# Count length of hasMany property

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I have a domain class:

```
class Person{
 static hasMany = [friends:Person]
 ....
}
```

What I'm looking to do is to filter out Persons based on the number of friends they have.

This is what I came up with, and it does the job:

```
Person.where{
 friends.size() == 3
}
```

It's slow as hell and I could do without the list, so ideally I'd just like to run something like:

```
select count(*) from Person where size(friends) == 3
```

I've searched like a maniac but I can't find that much information on countBy (I guess what I'm trying to do is countWhere).

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `where` query, you should be able to use `count()` instead of listing all the matches. `where` creates a [`DetachedCriteria`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#detachedCriteria) that supports a number of operations.

```
Person.where { friends.size() == 3 }.count()
```

If that doesn't work as well as I think it should, you might need to use a Criteria with a projection to only return the count.

```
Person.withCriteria {
    sizeEq 'friends', 3
    projections {
        rowCount()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a go and let you know how it goes.